# Let $G$ be Abelian. Then any subgroup of $G$ is normal. Does the converse hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I need a little help with the following problem of abstract algebra:

> Let $G$ an Abelian group. Clearly, any subgroup of $G$ is normal. Is the opposite true, that is if every subgroup of $G$ is normal, then $G$ is Abelian?

Comment: Can you add some of your own thoughts to how to proceed? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I see,can you tell me some examples of non-abelian group to check please?

Comment: Please do not title your questions with useless things like "Help with Abstract Algebra". In a case like this, the actual question you are addressing is a good title.

Answer (score 2):

The converse is not true. Think of the  quaternion group of order $8$, $Q=\{\pm 1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$. Can you see why this gives a counterexample?

Comment: Ok, Let me search about it . Thanks you.

Comment: I don't really recommend searching. The reason is not very difficult. First: what is the possible order of subgroups (Lagrange)?

Comment: Well, I suppose the posible order of a subgroup is always 2^n where n is the order of the group.

Comment: No. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then for sure we must have $|H|\le |G|$. That is the reason we have "sub" here. $H$ must be smaller than $G$ in some sense. Also Lagrange proved that $|H|$ must divides $|G|.$

Comment: I see, so, I just have to try for the subgroups wich may have order 1, 2, 4, and 8, rigth? By the way where I can check that things? I am completely new in this stuff. Some good book? to learn and master the material of the abstract algebra.

Comment: In fact you only need to check order 2 and 4, since order 1 must correspond to the trivial group and order 8 must correspond to $Q$ itself. Another hint to this question. There is only one subgroup of order $2$, and for the subgroup of order $4$, consider it's index.

Comment: For the book. I used Abstract algebra by Dummit and Foote

Comment: I got the subgruops in this case to be.
{-1,1},{-1,1,-i,i},{-1,1,-j,j},{-1,1,-k,k}.

Comment: For subgroup of order $2$ you are right. For subgroup of order $4$, there is more direct argument. Let $|H|=4$. Since $|G|=8$, the index $[G:H]=2$. Thus $H$ must be normal. This argument can be proved in general by considering left and right cosets. But in any case, you have what you wanted

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome :)